# how do i get an div to stay in place while text around it gets bigger or shorter

Tags: css, text

I have some text and then at the end of that, it has an spacer div which gives a margin gap so it separates it from the text below it.

The question is; how do i get the spacer div to stay in place whatever happens, while the length of the text above it gets shorter or longer without bringing the spacer div up in position with the text if the text is shorter?

anyone know the css for how to do it?

example:

```
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
loris ipsum, loris ipsum  
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
<span class="margin-space"></span>
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
```

what it does at the moment:

example:

```
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
loris ipsum, loris ipsum  
<span class="margin-space"></span>
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
*where text was*
*where text was*
```

(pulling the text below it up higher when I want it where it was originally)

how i want it, example:

```
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
loris ipsum, loris ipsum


<span class="margin-space"></span>
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
loris ipsum, loris ipsum
```

Hope you understood what I meant, any help?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle or give some more clues as to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  I think I know what you want, but I don't think you are going to achieve it the way you think you want it.  You want to keep a second block of text positioned at a certain height even if the text above it gets shorter.  What you need is to wrap the upper block of text in an element and set a `height` attribute to it, so that if the text in that block gets shorter than the height, the bottom block of text won't go any higher.

```
<p style="height: 100px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Cogito, ergo sum.</p>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3PkYT/3/

Comment: great but i already have css for <p> such as a margin top and bottom, because im using it somewhere else. what else could i use that would do the same thing?

Comment: the reason for this is because theyre are images next to the 2 sections of text and they need to be inline with them

Comment: Its okay ,Ive done it thanks to you. I made a span class and made the height of the box I wanted and bingo, so much thanks!